# $U\oplus W_1=V=U\oplus W_2$. implies $W_1=W_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U,W_1,W_2$ is subspace of vector space $V$, is true that

i)$U\oplus W_1=V=U\oplus W_2$. implies $W_1=W_2$

My answer is yes.

Let think that in opposite way such that $W_1\not = W_2$,to show that we are wrong. Since $V=U\oplus W_1$ that mean that every vector $x\in V$ can be written in unique way such that $x=x_1+x_2$, where $x_1\in U$ and $x_2\in W_1$, and $x_2\not \in W_2$.  The same way we can write for $U=V\oplus W_2, x=x_1+x_2´$, where $x_1\in U, x_2´\in W_2,$ and $x_2 \not \in W_1$. Then $x_1+x_2=x_1+x_2´$, from here $x_2=x_2´$ so $x_2\in W_2$ and $x_2´\in W_1$, so our first opinion is not true, and implies $W_1=W_2$.

Comment: From $U \oplus W_1 = V$, we know that every vector $x \in V$ can be written in a unique way as $x=x_1+x_2$ where $x_1 \in U$ and $x_2 \in W_1$. How do we know that $x_2 \notin W_2$ from this statement, which you seem  to have concluded?

Comment: I think that is not belong to show that i a wrong

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not true.

In your argument, you are assuming that the $U$-component of $x \in U \oplus W_1$ is the same as the $U$-component of $x \in U \oplus W_2$.

You should write instead: "[...] The same way we can write $x= x_1'+x_2'$, where $x_1' \in U$ and $x_2' \in W_2$".

After that, the argument breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Try $V=\mathbb R^2$, $U=\langle (1,0) \rangle$, $W_1=\langle (0,1) \rangle$, $W_2=\langle (1,1) \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is counterexaple:

Take $U =  \{(x,0); x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ (x-line)

$W_1 = \{(x,x); x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $W_2 = \{(x,-x); x\in\mathbb{R}\}$

Then $U\oplus W_1 = U\oplus W_2 = \mathbb{R}^2$ but $W_1\ne W_2$

Answer (score 1):

There are already answers giving counterexamples. So I am giving a necessary and sufficient condition under which your claim is true.
Suppose that $F$ is a field and $V$ is a vector space over $F$. Suppose that $P,Q,R$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $P\oplus Q=P\oplus R$. Then, $Q=R\iff P\cap(Q+R)=\{0\}$.

If $Q=R$ then, $Q+R=Q+Q=Q$ so, $P\cap(Q+R)=P\cap Q=\{0\}$.

Conversely, assume that $P\cap(Q+R)=\{0\}$. Let, $x\in Q$ then, $x\in P+Q=P+R$. So, $x=p+r$ for some $p\in P,r\in R$. Then, $p=x-r$ is in both $P$ and $Q+R$. But by hypothesis we then get, $p=0$ so, $x=r\in R$. So, $Q\subseteq R$. By symmetry we have, $Q=R$.